# Comparing EditText string with firebase database's child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app has a registration page wherein only those users who enter the right passcode are allowed to register. This passcode is stored inside firebase database inside a child called "Councilpasscodes". After entering the passcode the user should press the submit button, after comparing the two passcodes the user should be allowed to register if the passcodes are same.
This is the code for comparing the edit text string and the child value:

```
mpasscode=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Councilpasscodes"); 
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String passcode1=editText.getText().toString().trim();
                mpasscode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String passc= (String) dataSnapshot.child("passcode").getValue();
                        if (passcode1.equals(passc)){
                            //do something


                        }else if(!passcode1.equals(passc)){
                            //do something

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

[image: Database screenshot]

The problem is after pressing the submit button it is not really checking the two strings i.e. `if (passcode1.equals(passc))` and `if(!passcode1.equals(passc))` is not being called even after entering the right passcode. I am not sure what is wrong with the code as I am new to app development.Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I think it is not executing `addListenerForSingleValue` at all. I am not sure why is this happening.

Comment: Make sure you have read permission for that parent node in firebase database.By default, only authenticated users can access database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright mate. The reason why your `ValueEventListener`'s `onDataChange` isn't getting called is that you're not authorized to edit or read your database. This happens because the default security settings for a firebase real-time database disallows any read or write without an authenticated user. To prove this observe your `warning` logs inside Android Monitor. (The blue ones.) It will show a caught exception mentioning permission denied from Firebase as soon as you click submit.

Read about Firebase security from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

For a quick solution what you can do is, you can allow read or writes without any sort of authentication. To do that edit your Realtime database `rules` and add this instead of what's written there.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I'm also gonna attach a screenshot for reference. You'll find this screen inside the firebase [console](https://console.firebase.google.com). Inside the console click on your project and then on `Database` to the left as shown.

[image].

This is a security lapse none the less, so to set up proper Authentication from your app, follow these steps.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Also, add a toString() to `dataSnapshot.child("passcode").getValue()` like this to convert it to String as it's probably long.

`String passc = dataSnapshot.child("passcode").getValue().toString();`

Also, just to be sure. Add this line if you haven't already
`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`
above your 
`mpasscode=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Councilpasscodes");`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank u for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .compareTo() method? 
**if (passcode1.compareTo(passc) == 0) { }**

Answer (score 0):

I think firebase is returning integer instead. You can put the quote to 1234 and try again or compare as integer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using only numerics then `equalsIgnoreCase` would do good or if there is no limit of type of character you use in `counsilcode` then `.match` would be good