# Android & Firebase comparing EditText to realtime database child value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This question has been asked at: [Comparing EditText string with firebase database's child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734001/comparing-edittext-string-with-firebase-databases-child-value) and I am using that as a guide but coming into problems which were not solved there. I know Firebase offers authentication options, but I need to use realtime for the moment. I am looking to compare 2 values entered in my username and password EditTexts to the child values in my realtime database "Users".

[image]

When i run my code I get an

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

I'm assuming that either/both username1 and/or password1 are null and this is why my code is failing to run.

```
logUsername = findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsers);
logPassword = findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
final DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = logUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = logPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                mDatabaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String username1 = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                        String password1 = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();

                        if (username.equals(username1) & password.equals(password1)){
                            Intent intSignIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intSignIn);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

. I have both my read and write rules set to true. I'm new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The key is in this snippet of code:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
mDatabaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String username1 = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
        String password1 = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
```

Since you're loading from `/Users`, the `dataSnapshot` contains the data for **all** users. Each user's `username` and `password` are in a child node under `dataSnapshot`, which your code needs to handle.

The simplest way to do that from your current code is:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
mDatabaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String username1 = userSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            String password1 = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
        }
```

The big differences here are:

- I loop over the child nodes of the data snapshot to get to the snapshot for each individual user.
- I use `getValue(String.class)`, which will only return a value if `username` exists.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the reply. When changing my code to include the for loop you have above, both username1 and password1 in the below if statement turn red, with "Cannot resolve symbol". `if (username.equals(username1) & password.equals(password1)){
                            Intent intSignIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intSignIn);
                        }` Any ideas how this might be fixed?

Comment: I have tried putting that if statement into the for loop and it just displays the Toast that login was unsuccessful @Frank

Comment: I changed this `if (username.equals(username1) & password.equals(password1)){` to this `if (username1.equals(username) & password1.equals(password)){` and it is now working! Thank you so much for the help!!